# Simple CSS dropdown menu disappear when mouse over to the 2nd items

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I found a lot similar problems, but I couldn't find one similar to mine to resolve the problem.

Here's a link you can have a look of the full version.
http://pcdswa.org.au/

The sub menu disappears when you mouseover about half height of the 1st item. Cannot reach the 2nd at all.

The original dropdown CSS was copying from here
http://cssdeck.com/labs/another-simple-css3-dropdown-menu

Basically I haven't changed anything apart from the menu is now images but not texts.

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: are you using a particular browser? I can not replicate the issue you're experiencing. The top on .menu-items ul li ul is quite high which means it goes down the page and I can't over it at all, is that the issue?

Comment: I think the shortened html make the position different, I have deleted them now, the best to view my problems is from the link http://pcdswa.org.au/ Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great, thanks for the link. All you need to do now is add z-index to the .menu-items ul li ul like so:

```
 z-index: 9999;
```

You can find out more information about z-index here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp